# RxJS: how to combine two streams in one that fires events at a rate of one stream, but using latest values from other stream?

Tags: rxjs

I am very new to RX. Here is a simple model of a problem I am trying to solve. It looks easy, but I am having a hard time finding appropriate operators (or manipulating streams in some other manner) to solve it.

So let’s say we have two streams. One is emitting values frequently; the other far less so. We want every time the second observable emits a value, take the latest value that has been emitted by the other observable by that point, and do something with it.

**Non-working example:**

```
let stream1 = Rx.Observable
    .interval(100);

let stream2 = Rx.Observable
    .interval(2000)
  .combineLatest(stream1, (stream2Value, stream1Value) => stream1Value)
  .do((stream1Value) => console.log('value:', stream1Value));

stream2.subscribe();
```

The problem with the above snippet is that it will wait until the first emitted value from stream2 and then will start emitting a stream of events at the frequency of stream1. What I want is to get a stream that will fire events at the rate of stream2, but will emit latest values emitted by stream1 by the time stream2 fired. It sounds as if I need stream1 to become a behavior subject so that I could access its last value when stream2 fires... But maybe there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`withLatestFrom`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-withLatestFrom) to do that:

```js
let stream1 = Rx.Observable
  .interval(100);

let stream2 = Rx.Observable
  .interval(2000)
  .withLatestFrom(stream1, (stream2Value, stream1Value) => stream1Value)
  .do((stream1Value) => console.log("value:", stream1Value));

stream2.subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Also, depending upon your use case, you might find the [`auditTime`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-auditTime) operator useful.

Comment: Yasss! Just what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: This let me listen to route parameters and query parameters as a single stream in Angular 6. Thx!